# How to see disk usage of a VM instance on Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

we have a Ubuntu 14 running on a GCE VM instance. Nagios is alarming with low space disk and I'm trying to figure what's going on.

I see this VM has 1 Boot disk, 4 additional disks, and no Local disks. How can I find which disk is out of space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSH to your instance and execute the command `df`. This will show you the allocated and free space for each file system.

Comment: Does google have an alert system like whenever disk space is less than 10%, they notify via email?

Comment: @SandipSolanki - This is a good question that others will benefit from. Please create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Login to https://console.cloud.google.com
2. From top-left choose your project name
3. On left Dashboard, click on "Compute Engin" then "VM instances"
   [image]
4. Find your VM instance then click on “SSH” on the right side of that
   [image]
5. In Terminal use the following commands to go top proper folder and see how much space you used

- **ls**                                    (to see list of folders )
- **cd** floder-name                        ( to go to proper folder-name )
- **du -sh * | sort -hr | head -n10**       ( to see a list how space each folder or file has used )

**Note**: Usually project folder will be at **var/www/html** location

Answer (score 0):

**Clicking on the instance > heading to the Monitoring tab**

In that tab you will get all the info one can need about the instance in terms of CPU, memory, disk capacity and so on. One needs to first allow the operations agent and then it should be good to go